# Copy a new js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
this.listPoints: PointCollection
   items: Object
          480: PointObject
          500: PointObject
          700: PointObject
          default: PointObject
```

I have object `listPoints` that contains a list items as above. I want to add a new item (e.g. 600) to `listPoints` and this item contains all data/information of `default` item, and when changing any information in `600` then information of `default` is not affected. Please help.

Comment: What is this? Coffeescript?

Comment: @Juhana: Yea, I am using  `var new = $.extend(true, {},this.listPoints.items['default'])` to have a copy of `default` but type of `new` is `Object` while I hope type of `new` should be `PointObject`

Comment: If you want to merge the `default` object into a fresh instance, you should do something like `var n = $.extend(true, new PointObject(), this.listPoints.items['default']);`

Comment: @Niko: It does not work, because `PointObject` needs some parametters when initiating

Comment: And what prevents you from passing some?

Comment: If passing parametters, `new PointObject` will create a new `PointObject` that I don't need. I just need a copy. Another reason is it takes quite lot of time when creating a new `PointObject`, so I use copying an existing item instead of create a new one.

Comment: Well, you could also use the default object as the prototype of the new one but that doesn't really make a copy (but probably acts as expected most of the time): `var t = function() {}; t.prototype = this.listPoints.items['default']); var n = new t();`